# Given a class and its friend class, are the latter's inner classes automatically friends to the former class?

Tags: c++, friend, nested-class

I'm trying to use an open-source project.  Both the latest official (from a *.tar.gz file) and the bleeding-edge (from a SVN repository) versions do stuff like:

```
class Type1 {
    friend class Ridiculous;
    friend class Number;
    friend class Of_Friends;

    int  ImportantPrivateSemiSharedData;
};

 // In another header...

class Ridiculous {
    class Inner {
        void  MyFunc( Type1 &t )
        { /*do something with t.ImportantPrivateSemiSharedData*/ }
    };
};
```

AFAIK, marking `class A` as a `friend` of `class B` does **not** give any type associated with `A` `friend`ship rights with `B`.  Neither classes derived from `A` nor classes that are `friend`ly with `A` get `friend`ship with `B`.  I would think that limitation also applies to inner classes.

I'm using a computer from 2002 stuck several operating-system versions back, while the program (and presumably its design team) is mainly on newer computers.  Is my system compiler just old and busted, or are the new-hotness's compilers allowing something they shouldn't?  Is this a C++11 change?

I just want to use this program, but I keep getting stuck on things like this.  I'm already suspicious because the code is full of techniques like "private data with a ridiculous number of friends" and "inner classes everywhere," which I think are code smells.  The team is using these techniques together, but I think that they're fundamentally incompatible since `friend`ship doesn't carry over and you can't forward-declare inner classes.

(If it's needed, I'm using Mac OS X Tiger 10.4.11/PowerPC 32-bit (a G4-equipped eMac).  The program is LLVM and CLang (and LLVM Test Suite), trying from both the v3.0 archives and r153311 from Subversion.  The compiler is the Apple-supplied GCC 4.0.1 with XCode 2.5.)

### Addendum

Seeing the first responses, now I suspect that marking a class as a friend has two interpretations.  Given a `class A` that has a `friend class X` in it, that declaration can grant access to:

1. a member function (`static` or special or neither) of `X`.
2. any function, including special ones, whose fully-qualified name has the
   fully-qualified name of `X` as a prefix.

I think my compiler uses the first definition, while the writers' compiler uses the second.  Has there been official word to which interpretation is correct?  If so, when did the specification happen (C++98/03, a defect report, C++11)?  I've always thought friendship meant the first version (including C++ material I've read); the second never entered my mind until now.

Comment: That `Type1` is one of the sluttiest classes i've seen in a while, letting half the world mess with its privates....  Not judging, just saying.  :)

Comment: If you do not have a newer computer available you could still use ideone.com to test newer compiler versions.

Comment: Regarding the addendum, if class A has a friend class X (i.e. `class A { friend class X; ... };` then instances of class X can access the private members of class A. I think your two interpretations (at least the way I read them) has it backwards. As your and my examples show, even inner classes of class X benefit from class A's friendship with class X. You could think of adding a friend clause to a class declaration as being akin to opening a hole in its firewall: class A lets class X in. p.s. Thanks for accepting my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues at play here. One is that the code smells bad, as you say, and the second is that it doesn't compile on your system. Regarding the smell, yes, excessive use of the `friend` keyword often indicates bad OO design. It is generally better to give an object what it needs to do its job rather than pull something out of it, which is essentially what `friend` lets you do.

Large numbers of inner classes, IMO, are not that bad, as they merely serve to keep classes within the scope of another. This helps keep the namespace less cluttered and allows you to use common names across different functional areas.

Regarding the compilation issue, I tried to reproduce this on my system (Ubuntu 10.04, gcc 4.4.3, two years old at this point), and created this sample program:

```
class A
{
    friend class B;

    int x;
};

class B
{
    class Inner
    {
    public:
        void foo(A& a)
        {
            a.x++;
        }
    };

public:
    void bbb()
    {
        Inner i;
        A a;

        i.foo(a);
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    b.bbb();
}
```

This compiled with no errors or warnings. I initially had nothing marked public, but I needed to add `bbb()` to create an instance of class `Inner`, and I had to add a public method of `Inner` so I could invoke it to do something with an `A`.

The upshot is that I think your development system is out of date. The main developers clearly have no problem compiling their code, so the difference has to be with your system, or else they have configured their systems in a way that they are not telling you about. That being said, I think they could do more to make their code more portable and easier to build. In an open source project, that is to be expected if you want others to contribute.

Comment: Is the code always supposed to be legal, or was it added in C++11 or a defect report?  (I said the latter because I doubt there's any system compilers out now that require C++11.  And earlier ones don't have a C++11 mode.)  I think they use GCC for a boot-strapping compiler, maybe they (and you) are exploiting a GCC-specific quirk/extension.  The rules have changed before: (based on another SO query) C++11 now makes inner classes friends of their surrounding class; they weren't before.

Comment: @CTMacUser: The code was illegal, and I did not recall it being changed, but the fact is that it has been changed in the new standard. There is an explicit example in the c++11 standard showing this.

Comment: I don't think this is a C++11 feature. As I said, my compiler is gcc 4.4.3, which is [from](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) January 2010. Your compiler, gcc 4.0.1, is from July 2005, so is quite old and could easily have a problem with this code. You make a good point that gcc changes from time to time, but I would favor a newish version over a much older one, especially one so close to a major release (4.0.1 is close to 4.0, and might likely have many issues not known at the time of its release).